# compute $ \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-n) $

Tags: commutative-algebra, affine-schemes, groebner-basis

In order to study the equation $x^2 + y^2 = n$ I'd like to understand the related commutative ring
$$ R = \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-n)$$
I'd like compute the spectrum of this ring.  What are the prime ideals?

- $(x-a, y-b)$ with $a^2+b^2=n$
- if $p(x,y)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ 
  that is not a multiple of  $x^2 + y^2 = n$, then $(f(x,y))$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-n)$. This is like considering $(f(x,y), x^2+y^2-n)$ inside of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$.

Are there any others? These polynomials may correspond to [generic points](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_point) (also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89368/intuition-behind-generic-points-in-a-scheme))?

---

Certainly if $\mathbb{Z}$ is an [integral domain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain), so is  $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ and since  $x^2 + y^2 = n$ is irreducible, so is $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 = n)$.  This tells a few things, such as $(0)$ is prime.

it is not a [PID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain) e.g. $(2,x)$ is still prime.

---

Could there be a [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) approach.  Since $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is generated by monomials $x^a\, y^b$  maybe we could look at the images mod $x^2 + y^2 - n$.  In that case:

$$ x^a \,y^{2b+(0\text{ or  }1)} \equiv x^a \, (n - x^2)^b \,   y^{(0\text{ or  }1)} $$

At least, this would qualify what I mean by the word "compute".  The primes over $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ are the irreducibles and we could ask whether any of these [split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions) over $(x^2 + y^2 - n)$.

Comment: I don't understand what  the two last examples mean. Are you saying that for all of and q irreducible the ideal (p,q) has image a prime ideal in the quotient?

Comment: $(2,x)$ is not prime in $\mathbb Z[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 - n)$ if $2 \ | \ n$.

Comment: $(2,x)$ is never a prime in $R$, independently of whether $2$ divides $n$ or not :-)

Answer (score 1):

The ring $R=\mathbb Z[x,y]:= \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/\langle X^2+Y^2-n\rangle $ has Krull dimension $2$, so is certainly not a PID since PID's have Krull dimension $1$.
 Let's now have a look  at the scheme $S:=\operatorname {Spec}R$, which is an "arithmetic surface".

$\bullet$ The ring   $R$ has exactly one prime ideal of height zero: the zero ideal $\langle 0_R\rangle \subset R$.
It corresponds to the  generic point $\eta$ of the scheme $S$.

$\bullet \bullet$ The ring $R$ has  prime ideals of height $1$: such an ideal may be thought of as the generic point of an integral curve drawn on the surface $S$.
For example the prime ideal you mentioned, $\langle x-a,y-b \rangle$ where $a^2+b^2=n$, has height one.
But there might be other prime ideals of height one: for example if $n=3$ we may take the ideal $\langle x\rangle$.

$\bullet \bullet \bullet$ Finally we have the prime ideals of height two, which are exactly the maximal ideals of $R$.
They correspond to the closed points of our surface $S$.
Supposing again that $n=3$, the prime ideal $\langle x,y\rangle$ is such a maximal ideal.

Comment: thanks for the Google keyword. i haven't had time to surf through the rings and modules section of my Abstract Algebra textbooks. Or Atiyah-McDonald's